# What is the best way to Inject growing dependencies in the service class for unit test in java

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection

I have a Service class which is called from a controller(Jersey Restful api) where the service class instantiation happens.
This Service class contains all the business logic, so we have lot of other services, dao injected in this class. In order to test this class we created a constructor where we can inject those dependencies and mock things. Now the real problem is, as this service class's dependencies are growing, the constructor arguments are increasing and is difficult to maintain. is there any other solution/alternative to this.

I thought of creating setter method and injecting them but am not sure if that is ideal way of doing.

```
public ManageKitsService(NetworkService velosNetworkService, EmailService emailService, Environment environment, RestClient restClient, Properties properties, ManageKitsDao manageKitsDao, StudyDao studyDao) {
        this.NetworkService = NetworkService;
        this.emailService = emailService;
        this.environment = environment;
        this.restClient = restClient;
        this.properties = properties;
        this.manageKitsDao = manageKitsDao;
        this.studyDao = studyDao;
        .............
       ...............
        ...............
    }
```

In the unit test, we need to mock all these dependencies and pass to the constructor.
But if some one new dependency in the service class then we need to pass that in the constructor and change all the previous unit test Compilation errors.

```
            private ManageKitsDao mockManageKitsDao;
            private RestClient mockRestClient;

            @BeforeEach
            public void setUp() throws KitException {
               mockManageKitsDao = mock(ManageKitsDao.class);
                mockRestClient = mock(RestClient.class);
               ..............
               ................
             }  

        @Test
        public void itShouldRevokeAssignedKit() {
        when(mockManageKitsDao.getXXXX()).thenReturn(something)
        ...........some other mocking.............
            ManageKitsService manageKitsService = new ManageKitsService(mockNetworkService, mockEmailService, mockEnvironment, mockRestClient, mockProperties, mockManageKitsDao,
                            mockStudyDao);
   assertThatCode(() -> {
    manageKitsService.revokeAssignedKit(123, kitAssignment);
        }).doesNotThrowAnyException();
   }
```

Is there any best way to inject dependencies to mock things and write unit test.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `ManageKitsService` just a container for other services? You can write unit-tests for each service separately regardless `ManageKitsService`.

Comment: This is a design issue / code smell. If the constructor of that service is growing that is a sign that it is doing too much and violates the Single Responsibility Principle. You are focusing more on the symptoms rather than the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi I think you are right. this is the  design thing. That is how the code had written. But if we want to change the design , what approach you recommend

Comment: @Pradeep Review which functions use which dependencies and extract those out into their own classes/services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The false right solution : the reflection

Reflection (`@InjectMocks` and co) may solve your issue but it will just encourage you to make your design worse.

2) Design reworking

What you notice in your unit tests (to have a hard time to setup the class to test) is not the original issue. It is only the consequence of a design issue in the class under test.
Besides, writing unit tests with so many fine grained operations to mock is often hard to implement/read/maintain.
In the very most of cases, if you happen to have a constructor with many dependencies (six or more), it will probably mean that the dependencies used are too fine grained for the needs of this class.   You should try to introduce some higher level dependencies that aggregate/composes multiple dependencies processings.
Finally, that will improve both the design of the class and its test associated to.

Answer (score 0):

Using constructor injection is fine.  Many people (myself included) would argue that constructor injection is a better practice that method or field injection.

It looks like you're using Mockito, so rather than creating all of your mocks in a `@BeforeEach`-annotated method and then creating a new service in every test, you can do something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MyTestClass {

@Mock
private ManageKitsDao mockManageKitsDao;

@Mock
private RestClient mockRestClient;

@InjectMocks
private ManageKitsService manageKitsService

// Your service will automatically be instantiated with all of the mocks
// Now you can just write your tests like normal, using manageKitsService

}
```

The only real caveat here is that, if Mockito fails to inject a specific mock, it won't report failure.  So you need to be mindful to create a new `@Mock`-annotated member whenever you add a new variable to your constructor.  Though that should happen naturally, since you'll want to write tests around new functionality added by including a new dependency.